# Timeout inside a function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, wait

I've this code:

```
function divHideShow(divToHideOrShow) 
{
    var div = document.getElementById(divToHideOrShow);

    if (div.style.display == "none") 
    {
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
    else 
    {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

How to make it wait 2 seconds when executing div.style.display = "block"; ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to wait 2 seconds *before* setting to block, or *after*?

Comment: Then the answers here should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `setTimeout` to wait for a specified time (in milliseconds) before running some code.

```
function divHideShow(divToHideOrShow) 
{
    var div = document.getElementById(divToHideOrShow);

    if (div.style.display == "none") 
    {
        setTimeout(function () {
            div.style.display = "block";
        }, 2000);
    }
    else 
    {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

It might be worth considering adding and removing a class rather than setting the style directly. You can then handle all styles using CSS which helps with maintainability (and you can use CSS3 animations to fade/grow/shrink things in and out too).

Comment: display=none on the element directly seems fine to me, but I'd say instead of doing display=block to re-show it, just clear the display style.  That way you can define other display types in CSS (inline-block, float, etc) and this won't clobber it.

Comment: Thanks iblamefish! :-) It does its job!

Comment: @Recif when you think it answers your question... you should accept the answer so that answerer gets some encouragement

Answer (score 2):

This answers you question: the second parameter of `setTimeout` takes milliseconds so, `2000 milliseconds= 2 seconds`

```
function divHideShow(divToHideOrShow) 
{
    var div = document.getElementById(divToHideOrShow);

    if (div.style.display == "none") 
    {
        setTimeout(function(){div.style.display = "block";},2000);

    }
    else 
    {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

If you need `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` effects you better consider using jquery library:

You need to include `jquery` library in order this to be working.....

```
function divHideShow(divToHideOrShow) 
{

     var time=600;  //milli seconds alter this for changing speed
     $("#"+divToHideOrShow).fadeToggle(time);

}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work at all.  setTimeout will run the second argument after the timeout, it won't delay the rest of the code.

Comment: 2000 microseconds == 0.002 seconds.  That argument is *milliseconds*, where 2000 milliseconds == 2 seconds.

Comment: @Herms My badness, I typed microseconds though I intended milliseconds

Comment: how would it? I didn't implement it... I've suggested you :) I will add the example to the answer if you need though :)

Comment: @Recif do you know about jquery in first place?

Comment: @Recif see my eidted code for fadeToggle :) you can accept the answer by checking the tick mark below the up/down vote section

Comment: There is a problem: as it fade out, the divs are still visible and they go on bottom, changing the shape of the main div :-( http://jsfiddle.net/5sXmt/

Comment: @Recif you don't have enough reputation to vote up or down but you can still accept the answer by the '✓' mark on top left of the answer

Comment: @Recif you are maintaining two functions with the same name `divHideShow` and also it seems you didn't include jquery library

Comment: Ok, I've seen the answer mark!
Yes, I've included jquery (v1.10)

Comment: @Recif it's hard to look at the code some one written and find the errors, that too these are scripts.... if you have a specific question consider asking a new question....